# VHDL case found in a tutorial video online

Tags: vhdl

I was just trying to practice some VHDL programming which I came across a tutorial video on youtube. I saw an interesting challenging question which asked the viewer ti implement the foolowing case:

Can someone please help me as I am very new to VHDL and quite novice.

first, second, and third, are of std_logic_vector (7 downto 0):

second = first/4
third =  first rem 4

Comment: What does it mean to divide by a power of 2?  What does it mean to take the remainder with a power of 2?  Search on that.  Alternately, work through some example numbers and reason it out.  Once you understand that, the VHDL aspect is easy.

Comment: @JimLewis: I do not understand what you mean by divide by power of 2?I need to implement it using concatenation operator. Could u please give me a skeleton of the approach I should take to solve this question.

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried, and the *specific* problem or error message with your implementation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right, the answer is rather simple:

```
q <= 2x"0" & a(a'high downto 2);
r <= 6x"00" & a(1 downto 0);
```

Those `2x"0"`, `6x"00"` statements only work with the VHDL 2008 standard. On older language standards you could write `"00"` or `"000000"` respectively.